# Join Queries in Django

Tags: django

```
personel_id =models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=None)
    reservation_title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    reservation_situation = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I have got a model like that. Also I have got a Admin User Model. I just want to Fetch datas just related User ID. For example, User_id is 3 and Rezervastion_id = 3 I want to fetch Personel informations though this. My Query works on database, I just want to do it with Django ORM.

SELECT *
FROM reservation
LEFT JOIN auth_user ON reservation.personel_id_id = auth_user.id
WHERE reservation.id='pk' AND auth_user.id='pk'

Hello , I am trying to fetch result of this sql query in django. How can I do this Query using Django ORM's ?

Comment: Share your models and *what* you want to do. You should not think in terms of queries and joins, but models and use cases.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem "GET /?fname=c&email=asdxcaaaaaaaaad%40gmail.com&csrfmiddlewaretoken=UGmGeJ223ikZX4apKpvMvGzvn21BlO54y1Zjcbd4heGNfUKWbpFqeUG4fHJLEf36 HTTP/1.1" 200 4293 i am getting this value on submitting my form with Django. I want to save that email address not that fname is there any way to do that

Comment: You need to show us both models and tell us which fields exactly do you want + what do you want to do with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reservation = Reservation.objects.select_related('personel_id').filter(id=pk, personel_id__id=current_user)

Its done!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the `Reservation` with `id=3` and where the `personel_id_id` is `2` with:

```
Reservation.objects.get(
    id=3,
    personel_id_id=2
)
```

but `ForeignKey`s normally have *no* `…_id` suffix: Django will automatically add an `…_id` suffix for the field that stores the `id` of the user. You thus should implement your model as:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Reservation(models.Model):
    personel = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    reservation_title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    reservation_situation = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

and thus filter with:

```
reservation = Reservation.objects.get(
    id=3,
    personel_id=2
)
```

you can access the details of the user with `reservation.personel`, which is then a user model object.

If you want to fetch the user details in the same query, which thus saves an extra roundtrip to the database, you can use:

```
reservation = Reservation.objects.select_related('personel').get(
    id=3,
    personel_id=2
)
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: please help me  too fname=c&email=asdxcaaaaaaaaad%40gmail.com&csrfmiddlewaretoken=UGmGeJ223ikZX4apKpvMvGzvn21BlO54y1Zjcbd4heGNfUKWbpFqeUG4fHJLEf36 HTTP/1.1" 200 4293 i am getting this value on submitting my form with Django. I want to save that email address not that fname to the databse is there any way to do that

Comment: @ash: you probably want to use a `method="post"` in the `<form>`...

Comment: yes but don't know how can i only take email from the form and save it to backend

Comment: @ash: well `fname` should then not be listed under the `<form>`. The CSRF middlware is necessary to protect the server against cross-site request forgery.

Comment: i made a captcha system which validates fname is validation of js then acting like a step form moves to a email field but when i submit the form both of them comes. I amtryting to solve this from 3 days. Actually that's the reason why i started to use stackoverflow so much

Comment: @ash: can you ask a question with the necessary details to reproduce the problem together with a description what the expected result is?

Comment: ok but please wait here. Don't go away give me some time

Comment: i asked the question

Comment: Really really thanks for your help  but unfortunally thats not what I mean. I just want to list datas wich related another table's row.

Comment: @EngineerGuitarist: but there is *at most* one record, since you filter on the primary key, and as specified in the answer, you can access the data of the user (`personel`) with `reservation.personel`.

Comment: Data is coming , But I want to ask you another question. How can apply "where" condition?     SELECT * FROM reservation LEFT JOIN auth_user ON reservation.personel_id_id = auth_user.id WHERE reservation.id='pk' AND auth_user.id='pk' ... Like that ..

Comment: @EngineerGuitarist: we do that: that is what the `id=3` and `personel_id=2` is doing: we filter on the `id` of the reservation and the `id` of the `personal` (so `user` table).